# RbConfig ruby_version mismatch

Tags: ruby

When I run the following Ruby code:

```
require 'rbconfig'
puts RbConfig::CONFIG["ruby_version"]
```

It returns "2.2.0". However, when I run "ruby -v" or "rbenv version", it returns "2.2.3".

What could be causing RbConfig to report the wrong Ruby version?